# Generic Function: Cast T[] to Complex[]

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, casting

I need a function that works on any either real-valued or complex-valued array.

However, for the function itself, it is very convenient to work on a `Complex[]`-Array. Therefore I want to typecast any array which is not of type `Complex[]` (e.g. `double[]` or `byte[]` or `int[]`...) to `Complex[]`.

I thought this might be a nice exercise for myself to write a small generic function:

```
private static Complex[] convertArrayToComplex<T>(T[] inpArr)
{
    if (typeof(T) != typeof(Complex[]))
    {
        Complex[] inpArrC = new Complex[inpArr.Length];
        for (int k = 0; k < inpArr.Length; k++)
        {
            inpArrC[k] = new Complex((double)(object)inpArr[k], 0);
        }
        return inpArrC;
    } else
    {
        return inpArr; // Compiler-Error is here
    }
}
```

Of course this does not work: I get the Compiler-Error telling me, that `T[]` cannot implicitly casted to `Complex[]`. I do understand this, but I do not see a way to achieve my goal in an elegant fashion.

Constraints: I know that `inpArr` is a numeric Array.

Comment: You can try this. `return (Complex[]) inpArr;`

Comment: Thanks. But I need to return `Complex[]`. This will give me an error "`T` cannot be casted to `Complex[]`"

Comment: Why are you taking an array of `T` when you clearly need an array of `double`? Why isn't the method defined as `convertArrayToComplete(double[] inpArr)`?

Comment: Generic methods should behave uniformly for all types `T` so you should avoid this kind of type checking. In this case your function only works for `double[]` inputs since the `(double)(object)inpArr[k]` cast will fail for any other type.

Comment: Are you actually looking for `Convert.ToDouble(inpArr[k])` ? that examines the actual underlying value type and figures out the right way to convert to or extract the double?

Comment: Perhaps you need to do a `where T : IConvertible` and use the `ToDouble()` method?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yes, I think I was looking for Convert.ToDouble

Comment: What kind of types do you intend to pass for `T`?

Comment: at least for now `byte[], int[], double[], complex[]`

Comment: I would suggest you write 4 overloads that creates an array of the right type and calls the actual, fifth, implementation. That way you have control over what types are *actually* allowed, not just what would *happen* to work.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen okay thank you for the suggestion. I see my solution is far from perfect. Creating four overloads on the other hand makes some "code overhead", doesn't it? Also, in future, you need to extend the code for further numerical data types if necessary. This is why I assumed a generic function to be a good candidate in the first place...
(It's no important project and was rather for self-exercise.)

Comment: 4 of these ? `private static Complex[] convertArrayToComplex(byte[] inpArr) => convertArrayToComplete(inpArr.Select(i => (double)i).ToArray());`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116095/discussion-between-vincent-and-lasse-v-karlsen).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can know the type is equal, but you still have to convince the compiler. Also, I would make the code clearer by using `is` instead of type checking:

```
private static Complex[] convertArrayToComplex<T>(T[] inpArr)
{
    if (inpArr is Complex[])
    {
        return (Complex[])(object)inpArr;
    }

    Complex[] inpArrC = new Complex[inpArr.Length];

    for (int k = 0; k < inpArr.Length; k++)
    {
        inpArrC[k] = new Complex(Convert.ToDouble(inpArr[k]), 0);
    }

    return inpArrC;
}
```

Comment: You should probably replace `(double)(object)inpArr[k]` with `Convert.ToDouble(inpArr[k])`, which will work for many other array types (ie `int[]`, `float[]` etc)

Comment: That is a good suggestion. Although this was de code of OP which already seemed to work, so I did't want to fiddle too much with that.

Comment: Good suggestion, I will accept the answer in five minutes... that was fast :)

Comment: How about replacing the second part with `return inpArr.Select(number => new Complex(Convert.ToDouble(number), 0)).ToArray();`?

Comment: Nice suggestion, if one uses Linq.